# Selenium webdriver inside a docker with Python

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, folium

I'm trying to execute a selenium firefox inside a docker.

```py
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

When i run the code locally that work fine, then i try to run it in a docker on a remote server and get the following error:

```
ief description */
#error p {
}

/* some data which may have caused the problem */
#data {
}

/* the error message received from the system or other software */
#sysmsg {
}

pre {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

/* special event: FTP / Gopher directory listing */
#dirmsg {
    font-family: courier;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#dirlisting {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
#dirlisting tr.entry td.icon,td.filename,td.size,td.date {
    border-bottom: groove;
}
#dirlisting td.size {
    width: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/* horizontal lines */
hr {
        margin: 0;
}

/* page displayed footer area */
#footer {
        font-size: 9px;
        padding-left: 10px;
}


body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
 --></style>
</head><body id=ERR_CONNECT_FAIL>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://localhost:58533/session">http://localhost:58533/session</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Connection to ::1 failed.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p id="sysmsg">The system returned: <i>(111) Connection refused</i></p>

<p>The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo%20-%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20proxy-dmz-01%0D%0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL%0D%0AErr%3A%20(111)%20Connection%20refused%0D%0ATimeStamp%3A%20Mon,%2018%20Sep%202023%2009%3A08%3A59%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%3A%20137.121.3.124%0D%0AServerIP%3A%20localhost%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0APOST%20%2Fsession%20HTTP%2F1.1%0AAccept-Encoding%3A%20identity%0D%0AContent-Length%3A%20284%0D%0AAccept%3A%20application%2Fjson%0D%0AContent-Type%3A%20application%2Fjson%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8%0D%0AUser-Agent%3A%20selenium%2F4.12.0%20(python%20linux)%0D%0AX-Forwarded-For%3A%20137.121.198.250%0D%0AHost%3A%20localhost%3A58533%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A">webmaster</a>.</p>

<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Mon, 18 Sep 2023 09:08:59 GMT by proxy-dmz-01 (squid/3.4.8)</p>
<!-- ERR_CONNECT_FAIL -->
</div>
</body></html>
```

I do not understand why i get a "html/css" error and what can i do to resolve it.

I already try to add option

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

and a driver_service:

```
driver_service = Service("path/to/firefox_driver")
```

i  also test with Chrome but i get the same error

Comment: The HTML response has some detail in it which could get you closer to the solution

http://localhost:58533/session
The system returned: (111) Connection refused
Generated by proxy-dmz-01 

This could be related to environmeltal specifics in the container, maybe it's a service that should be listeningon that port 58533 but isn't. Without the complete picture of the actual container inside its dedicated enviroment it's unfortunately not possible to determine where the connection is blocked